# Can someone explain how setting __webpack_public_path__ works?

Tags: webpack

I'm new to webpack module bundler.

How do I use **webpack_public_path** ?
do I need to set it something like this

`var __webpack_public_path__ = 'http://some.cdn.com/assert/`

Can someone explain how setting **webpack_public_path** works?

Thanks & Regards

Adi

Comment: Can you try setting `output.publicPath`? I don't know what you are trying to achieve here based on the question.

Comment: Solved - https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution at [Github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2673), posting the same.

> import is hoisted, so it always runs before the code inside of your module.
>
> You probably have the use require in the entry point.

Comment: can you please provide the github link for the solution?